# How can I make n by adding k non-negative integers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose I have 3 non-negative integers and I have to achieve 4 by adding these numbers .There are 15 ways to get 4 by adding 3 non-negative integers . They are

```
1.      0 0 4
2.      0 1 3
3.      0 2 2
4.      0 3 1
5.      0 4 0
6.      1 0 3
7.   1 1 2
8.   1 2 1
9.   1 3 0
10.  2 0 2
11.  2 1 1
12.  2 2 0
13.  3 0 1
14.  3 1 0
15.  4 0 0
```

I want to know the number of ways to get n by adding k non-negative integers . n and k can be very big . (1 ≤ k ≤ 10^6) , (0

Comment: Classic stars and bars problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classic stars and bars problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics).

You have a string of 4 stars and 2 bars (to split it into 3 pieces, one for each variable), there are a total of $\binom{4+2}{2} = \binom{4+2}{4} = \frac{6!}{4!2!} = 15$ such strings, each corresponding to a unique assignment, so there is 15 assignments...

Comment: What is meant by "2 bars" ? Is it "k-1" ??

Comment: @SultanAhmedSagor Yes, in general case, you are looking for ways to get $n=4$ using $k=3$ integers, and the result is $n$ starts, $k-1$ bars, to $\binom{n+k-1}{n} = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.